# Où vont les pièces dans un casse-tête/puzzle en bois et quel est le nom des trucs servant à les manipuler ?

Tags: vocabulaire, jeux

[image]

Dans ce genre de [casse-tête/puzzle](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871815) pour enfant en bois, comment désigne-t-on couramment les endroits dans lesquels il faut placer les pièces et les trucs (rouges) qui servent à les manipuler ? On peut par exemple penser à une phrase comme :

> Tu dois placer les pièces (aux *bons endroits*, mais encore) en les
> manipulant avec les [trucs rouges].

Answer (score 2):

> Tu dois ranger les pièces dans les bon emplacements en les manipulant avec les boutons/manettes rouges.

Comment: Est-ce que *cheville* marcherait aussi pour le bouton ?

Comment: Pas en France où le mot est trop lié à la cheville du pied ou éventuellement à celle dans laquelle on visse quelque chose dans un mur.

Comment: Est-ce que tu emploierais _ranger_ aussi avec un 1000 pièces « standard » ?

Comment: Non, j'ai remplacé *placer* par *ranger* uniquement pour éviter la répétition avec *emplacements*. Pour un vrai puzzle, *ranger* n'est plus adapté puisqu'il n'y a plus d'endroit absolu où les ranger. Dans ce cas ce pourrait être *placer* ou *disposer* par exemple.

Comment: Fiou ! Là j'avais commencé à imaginer ce différent rapport à la matérialité des objets vu un univers socioréférentiel différent, qui justifierait une nuance sémantique du verbe hahaahahah impayable, pas autant que juté au jeu de paume mais quand même. Apprendre c'est aussi infirmer des hypothèses, et heureusement parce que c'est souvent facile de partir sur une balloune hahahha.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne sais pas si c'est mon souvenir à Montréal, ce que j'aurais entendu il y a longtemps ou un lexique par défaut que j'emploierais par association selon les caractéristiques concrètes d'un objet, mais je crois que j'aurais spontanément dit :

> Tu dois placer les pièces dans les *trous/[forme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/forme)s* et les manipulant avec
> les (p)tites [*poignées*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poign%C3%A9e) (rouges).

*Trou* est une simplification alors que *forme* est peut-être métonymique ; *poignée* m'est très usuel.

Comment: Oui, ça passerait très bien ici aussi.